# Django related_name in Models

Tags: python, django, models

Any suggestions on the proper configuration of `related_name` in models.py to create a category and subcategory structure? Error when running `syncdb`:

`myapp.category: Accessor for field 'parent' clashes with related field 'Category.children'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'parent'.
myapp.category: Reverse query name for field 'parent' clashes with related field 'Category.children'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'parent'.
myapp.subcategory: Accessor for field 'parent' clashes with related field 'Category.children'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'parent'.
myapp.subcategory: Reverse query name for field 'parent' clashes with related field 'Category.children'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'parent'.`

I'm trying to make a category/subcategory structure. For example, parent categories are soda companies (Coke, Pepsi, etc) and subcategories are types of soda (cola, sparkling water, etc.) A subcategory can be related to different parent categories, and vice versa.

Here are the models that I'm having problems figuring out (using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/)):

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
   site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
   template_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

       def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name + u' Category'

class SubCategory(MPTTModel):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   parent = TreeForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name + u' SubCategory'
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call both the recursive relationship on Category and the FK from SubCategory to Category "children". Pick a different name for one of them.

I must say, though, that this doesn't seem like a good fit for MPTT at all. Companies don't fall into a tree relationship, as they are presumably all on the same level, and neither do soda types: what would it mean for "cola" to be a child of "sparkling water", for example? Sounds like you want a simple ManyToMany relationship from Company to SodaType, so that each company can have many soda types and each type can be made by several companies.

Comment: Wanted to use mptt because the relationships will be much deeper than the soda / company analogy that I referenced above. Thank you very much for the great advice.